# Convert Matlab struct to python/numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have a small snippet of matlab code I would like to translate the python/numpy

```
for i = 1:numel(order)
%This puts all output data into one variable, alongside the scan length
%and separation
plotout = [plotout; resout(i).output ...
    repmat((i-1)*separation,[length(resout(i).output) 1]) ...
    transpose(0:0.004712:(length(resout(i).output)*0.004712)-0.004712)];
end
```

I have made an attempt using np.matlibrepmat in replacment of repmat, however I am unsure how to continue specifically with the last line `transpose(0:0.004712:(length(resout(i).output)*0.004712)-0.004712)];`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is `resout`?

Comment: resout.output(i) is a 2d struct containing multiple float values

Comment: Correction - resout.output(i) is 1 dimensional

Comment: But you write `resout(i).output`.  Everything in MATLAB is at least 2d.

Comment: @Seb fyi, `resout(i).output` is not the same as `resout.output(i)`. The first one accesses the property `output` of the object `resout(i)`, whereas the latter accesses the first element of the property `output` from some object `resout`. The second is illegal syntax if `resout` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That last line produces a column vector to be appended along side the other column vectors.

The code

`(0 : 0.004712 : (length(resout(i).output)*0.004712)) - 0.004712`

counts from `0` to `(length(resout(i).output)*0.004712)` at a step size of `0.004712`, then subtracts `0.004712` from each element.

This is equivalent to something like:

`np.arange(0, (len(resout(i).output)*0.004712), 0.004712) - 0.004712`

which is a row vector of some size `[1,N]`. The resulting row vector is then transposed into a column vector `[N,1]`.

In numpy this can be done by something like

```
A = np.arange(0, (len(resout(i).output)*0.004712), 0.004712) - 0.004712
np.reshape(A, (len(A), 1))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!